# Visual studio не видит добавленных библиотек

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Сейчас делаю проект на Unity. В Visual Studio 2017 пишу код для него. Внутри решения имеется 3 проекта.

[image: Каталог решения]

В каждом из них в ссылках есть библиотеки

[image: Библиотеки]

Однако когда я пытаюсь в проекте использовать:

```
using System.Drawing.Primitives
```

Студия в упор не видит. Я создал чистое консольное приложение и там заработало сразу. Мне нужны компоненты bitmap и image а они хранятся именно в этой библиотеке. Если напрямую использовать библиотеку `System.Drawing`, то студия видит только:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Я бы вам не советовал использовать System.Drawing в проектах которые не буду предназначены только для windows net framework. А не видит он из скорее всего кок раз из-за Unity

Comment: @Vasek а что тогда делать? Мне нужны классы BitMap и Image

Comment: Попробуй System.Drawing.Common поставить. Вроде, это кроссплатформенная реализация https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoYouUseSystemDrawingInNETCore.aspx

Comment: Я бы обратил внимание на либы которые описаны в сылке выше, внизу статьи.

Comment: Для понимания почему не работает советую почитать [это](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1379519/systemdrawing-namespace-not-consistently-found-uni.html). И еще [здесь](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/118975/alternative-to-system-drawing-for-breaking-an-image-into-separate-tiles-in-unity) есть не плохой совет что возможно, что вам нужно есть в самом Unity.